# Why bean is initialized multiple times during junit tests?

Tags: java, spring, junit

Can you please help me to understand why the following happens?
I have the following bean:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

public class TestBean implements BeanPostProcessor {
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Initialized!");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Destroyed!");
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("postProcessBeforeInitialization");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("postProcessAfterInitialization");
        return null;
    }
}
```

with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="TestBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy"/>
</beans>
```

and the following junit tests:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:beans1.xml"})
public class TestBeanTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestBean collectionBean;

    @Test
    public void testCollectionBean() {
    }
}
```

And now, what surprises me, is that if I run that unit tests, "postProcessBeforeInitialization" and "postProcessAfterInitialization" are printed 5 times each. What is the reason? Shouldn't they be printed 1 time only, during bean initialization?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the `testCollectionBean` method actually do ?

Comment: How much `@Test` methods do you have in your test class?

Comment: @Arnaud Nothing. It is left empty on purpose.

Comment: @StefanBirkner this test class I put there is complete - there is only one, empty test

Comment: There are beans which are configured by Spring itself. Try: `System.out.println("postProcessBeforeInitialization " + beanName);` . Only one of them should be yours

Comment: Put a breakpoint and the init()"method and start the unit test in debug mode, so that you are 100% sure it is called 5 times

Comment: @OriDar I don't get it... There is only one bean that prints out "postProcessBeforeInitialization" and this is my TestBean. If I remove this println from TestBean, no "postProcessBeforeInitialization" is printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To recap on my comment:

With a slight change to `TestBean` bean post processor `postProcessBeforeInitialization` method:

```
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("postProcessBeforeInitialization " + beanName);
    return null;
}
```

And possible minimal Spring dependency: `org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.2.RELEASE`

The output for your code is:

```
postProcessBeforeInitialization org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
postProcessBeforeInitialization org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
postProcessBeforeInitialization TestBeanTest
```

*Conclusion*: the bean is post processed only once by the post processor, the rest are Spring's own beans. The fact that you get 5 and I get only 3 is the different dependencies set we are using.

Also, note that `TestBean` is not even considered (printed) as it's not a bean, but rather a bean post processor.

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation and the method signature should help you understand the problem.

> Factory hook that allows for custom modification of new bean
>   instances,   e.g. checking for marker interfaces or wrapping them with
>   proxies

I would suggest that you also print out the bean name. This will show you the beans like EventlistnerFactories and other factory methods which are injecting your beans programatically. So this method is called for each of those beans before that injection happens giving you an opportunity to proxy or wrap your bean if required.